# How to load bmp file using x11 window background

Tags: c++, linux, x11, embedded-linux, xlib

I try to set background image in x11 window using bmp file. I have using XReadBitmapFile but its not working. How can i use bmp file to set x11 window background. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you _show_ us what you've tried?

Comment: GC gc = XCreateGC ( d, w, 0 , NULL );
int resource = XReadBitmapFile(d, w, "demo.bmp", &width, &height, &bitmap, &x, &y); 
XCopyPlane(d, bitmap, w, gc, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XReadBitmapFile is for reading .xbm files only. What is needed is a library for reading BMP files, one possibility is ImLib2 which can read numerous types of files and works well with Xlib.

Here is a longish example of using it:

```
/* displays an image or sets root background
 * PUBLIC DOMAIN - CC0 http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/
 * J.Mayo 2013
 *
 * gcc -Wall -W -g3 -o xrootbg xrootbg.c -lX11 -lImlib2
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Imlib_Image img;
    Display *dpy;
    Pixmap pix;
    Window root;
    Screen *scn;
    int width, height;
    const char *filename = NULL;

    if (argc < 2)
        goto usage;
    filename = argv[1];

    img = imlib_load_image(filename);
    if (!img) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:Unable to load image\n", filename);
        goto usage;
    }
    imlib_context_set_image(img);
    width = imlib_image_get_width();
    height = imlib_image_get_height();

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!dpy)
        return 0;
    scn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(dpy);
    root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    pix = XCreatePixmap(dpy, root, width, height,
        DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));

    imlib_context_set_display(dpy);
    imlib_context_set_visual(DefaultVisualOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_colormap(DefaultColormapOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_drawable(pix);

    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(0, 0);
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(dpy, root, pix);
    XClearWindow(dpy, root);

    while (XPending(dpy)) {
        XEvent ev;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
    }
    XFreePixmap(dpy, pix);
    imlib_free_image();
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
usage:
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <image_file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Now its working Thank you. Is there any manual for "Imlib2" to know about various APIs in Imlib2

Comment: [link](http://docs.enlightenment.org/api/imlib2/html/) has complete docs and some useful examples. Imlib2 is just one of many libraries available to do this, they all work roughly the same. But others might require you to use XImage instead of doing the rendering for you, but XImage is pretty simple and part of standard xlib.